# How do I create a nicely formatted directory with mail merge in Microsoft Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, mail-merge

I am trying to create a directory with mail merge in Microsoft Word 2007 and I hit a few issues.

```
«Forename» «Surname»
«Address_Line_1»
«Address_Line_2»
«Address_Line_3»
«Address_Line_4»
«Postcode»
«Home_Phone»
«Mobile_Phone»
«email»
«Other_Details_1»
«Other_Details_2»
```

I get blank lines in the director when a field does not have any date, e.g. `<<Address_Line_4>>` is often empty.   There must be an easy way to remove empty lines I just can’t find it.

I have selected all the fields and on paragraph dlg box set the “keep lines together” and “keep with next”,  however when a column is started there is often blank lines before the first field is outputted and lots of space at the bottom of some pages.

Comment: (1) are you actually merging, i.e. by creating a new output document, or are you just previewing the merge? (What happens when you preview is not identical to what happens when you actually complete the merge). (2) when, e.g., <<Address_Line_4>> is blank, is the result of the field actually empty? You can check by changing the line to, say, x<<Address_Line_4>>x and seeing if you get lines like "x x", "x  x" etc. as a result, rather than just "xx".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that "Don't print blank lines when data fields are empty" is enabled. Also make sure that you are using paragraph breaks and not line breaks as the latter is not supported by this option.

1. Click the ribbon - > Options-> Customize
2. Select "All commands" in the "Choose Commands From" drop down
   list.
3. Locate *Mail Merge Helper* in the list and add it to the
       Quick Access Toolbar (QAT) column on the right.
4. Click OK. The Mail Merge Helper icon should now appear in the QAT. e. Click that
           button and click the Merge... button. Make sure that "Don't print
           blank lines when data fields are empty" is checked.